# Reading JWT Token from API in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

My setup: I've created and have running a WebAPI solution that performs the authentication of a username and password against a source (currently a db). This generates the JWT token and returns it to the requesting app (a ASP.NET Core 2.2 app).

Most solutions talk of securing the WebAPI exposed methods but my approach is to only do the authentication through WebAPI.  The individual apps need to accept the token so they can determine authorization.

Now the question: what is the best approach to reading the token from the WebAPI (which I've done already), validating it, and then storing it for any/all controllers to know there is an authenticated user (via Authorize attribute) so long as the token is valid?

Debugging this more, it seems my token is not being added to the headers. I see this debug message:

> Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizeFilter'

**Code Update2** - code that gets the JWT:

```cs
        var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_configuration.GetSection("SecurityApi:Url").Value);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        //login
        Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = ValidateUserAsync(client, username, password);
        Task<Core.Identity.TokenViewModel> tokenResult = response.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<Core.Identity.TokenViewModel>();

        if (!response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            if (tokenResult != null && tokenResult.Result != null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", tokenResult.Result.ReasonPhrase);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", AppStrings.InvalidLoginError);
            }
            return View();
        }

        JwtSecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityToken(tokenResult.Result.Token);
        int userId;

        if (int.TryParse(token.Claims.First(s => s.Type == JwtRegisteredClaimNames.NameId).Value, out userId))
        {
            //load app claims
            Core.Identity.UserInfo userInfo = Core.Identity.UserLogin.GetUser(_identityCtx, userId);
            Core.Identity.UserStore uStore = new Core.Identity.UserStore(_identityCtx);
            IList<Claim> claims = uStore.GetClaimsAsync(userInfo, new System.Threading.CancellationToken(false)).Result;
            claims.Add(new Claim(Core.Identity.PowerFleetClaims.PowerFleetBaseClaim, Core.Identity.PowerFleetClaims.BaseUri));

            ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

            //complete
            AuthenticationProperties authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties();
            authProperties.ExpiresUtc = token.ValidTo;
            authProperties.AllowRefresh = false;
            authProperties.IsPersistent = true;

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, tokenResult.Result.Token);
            //var stuff = HttpContext.SignInAsync(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, authProperties);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", AppStrings.InvalidLoginError);
            return View();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Startup:

```
private void ConfigureIdentityServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.LoginPath = "/Login");

        //authentication token
        services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
        {
            opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddCookie(opt =>
        {
            opt.LoginPath = "/Login";
            opt.LogoutPath = "/Login/Logoff";
            opt.Cookie.Name = Configuration.GetSection("SecurityApi:CookieName").Value;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = Configuration.GetSection("SecurityApi:Issuer").Value,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = Configuration.GetSection("SecurityApi:Issuer").Value,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("SecurityApi:Key").Value)),
                ValidateLifetime = true
            };
        });

        Core.Startup authStart = new Core.Startup(this.Configuration);
        authStart.ConfigureAuthorizationServices(services);
    }
```

Auth:

```
public void ConfigureAuthorizationServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<Identity.IdentityContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SecurityConn")));
        services.AddScoped<DbContext, Identity.IdentityContext>(f =>
        {
            return f.GetService<Identity.IdentityContext>();
        });

        services.AddIdentityCore<Identity.UserInfo>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<Identity.IdentityContext>().AddRoles<Identity.Role>();
        services.AddTransient<IUserClaimStore<Core.Identity.UserInfo>, Core.Identity.UserStore>();
        services.AddTransient<IUserRoleStore<Core.Identity.UserInfo>, Core.Identity.UserStore>();
        services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<Core.Identity.Role>, Core.Identity.RoleStore>();

        services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
        {
            auth.AddPolicy(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
            auth.AddPolicy(PFBaseClaim, policy => policy.RequireClaim(Identity.PFClaims.BaseUri));
        });
    }
```

Comment: So essentially your WebAPI is an Identity Provider. In your other APIs, you need to set up some sort of Bearer Token Authentication. This configuration will have to have everything it needs to validate the token. There's several ways to do this.. BUT. If this is a new project, I'd highly suggest you take a look at Identity Server. It is an Identity Provider that offers everything you need, plus it implements OAuth and OpenId Connect, so you are covered. Then addin authentication on your other APIs is very easy.

Comment: This show some examples on how to enable bearer token authentication
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/03/23/token-authentication-aspnetcore-complete-guide

Comment: Not quite an Identity Server, just to authenticate.  No other API's for security. This is an existing DB from over 10 years ago that did not use any ASPNET identity tables. It even has its own claims generation. What I'm trying to do is write a more modern version of authentication using JWT and be able to pick up the claims with existing procedures.

Comment: If you already provided a way of returning jwt tokens after a user is authenticated, it's just a matter of, in the other APIs validating that token. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-2.2#jwt-bearer-authentication

Comment: I must be missing something obvious because controllers that are marked off for Authorized do not pick up anything showing a user has been authenticated.  Does the token get put into a header? Cookie? How can I verify the app picked up the token and has it to use?

Comment: In your "client" API, you will add the `services.AddAuthentication` middleware and provide the parameters used to verify the token. When a request comes in, it has the token in the `Bearer` header. The framework will use the parameters to validate the token, and if okay it will authenticate the user, then it's able to access the controllers that have the `[Authorize]` endpoint. If you inspect the HttpContext, you'll see a ClaimsIdentity and inside all the claims that were contained in the jwt token.

Comment: Perhaps that is where my problem is.  This is the code I'm using to call the API on post to get the token:

Comment: The code seems okay to me. Maybe change the last line to `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);`. But how does it look in the API you are trying to call? Did you add the `services.AddAuthentication` middleware there? How are you generating the jwt tokens? Using some library or manually?

Comment: Manually. The API has some middleware setup to it however the calls are not meant to have security behind them. They are ONLY meant to issue the token. It is the ASP.NET app that needs the security. Assume the token is valid and the app is running from a different domain, it seems to me the middleware is not aware of the token except the fact that there was a postback to get it.

Comment: Want to move this to a chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189916/question-55128922

Comment: looks like I'm still too much of a noob to post in chat. I'll be working on this and try to get back to you to see if adding the header works. So far, no go.

Comment: No worries. To be fair, the chat sucks anyway. If you have gitter, you can hit me there as well. http://gitter.im. my username is `joaopgrassi`. If it helps, I recently wrote a blog post that has this stuff inside. https://github.com/joaopgrassi/httpclient-token-identityserver/tree/master/src/Clients Here you can find a "ProtectedAPI" which receives jwt tokens and has one `Authorize` endpoint and the "Client" which gets the access tokens and use them to call this protected API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, my approach was to use a secure cookie and a base claim to prove the user authenticated.

private void ConfigureAuthentication(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.LoginPath = "/Login");

```
        //authentication token
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(opt =>
        {
            opt.LoginPath = "/Login";
            opt.AccessDeniedPath = "/Login";
            opt.LogoutPath = "/Login/Logoff";
            opt.Cookie.Name = Configuration.GetSection("SecurityApi:CookieName").Value;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.SaveToken = true;

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = Configuration.GetSection("SecurityApi:Issuer").Value,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = Configuration.GetSection("SecurityApi:Issuer").Value,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("SecurityApi:Key").Value)),
                ValidateLifetime = true
            };
        });
    }
```

And at login:

```
            AuthenticationProperties authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties();
        authProperties.ExpiresUtc = token.ValidTo;
        authProperties.AllowRefresh = false;
        authProperties.IsPersistent = true;

        HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, userStore.CreateAsync(user).Result, authProperties);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```